# Проблемы с открытием окна.

Tags: ооп, javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться со следующей ситуацией:

`Ext Designer` (программа визуального конструирования `ExtJs`) выводит два файла с готовой программой. Первый выглядит так (EditingTemplateWindow.js):

```
EditingTemplateWindow = Ext.extend(EditingTemplateWindowUi, {
    initComponent: function() {
        EditingTemplateWindow.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

Во втором непосредственно реализация всего:

```
EditingTemplateWindowUi = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    // Реализация всего ....
    // ... .... .... .... 
});
```

Дальше, все это прекрасно запускается от следующего кода:

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        var cmp1 = new EditingTemplateWindow({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        cmp1.show();
    });
```

И проблема возникает вот в чем. Я в своей программе, по образцу пытаюсь открыть мое это окно. Делаю так:

```
//Глобальная переменная
var editingTemplateWindow;

// Логика программы на ExtJs... ... ...
//Что-то произошло, и надо вывести пользователю мое окно:
editingTemplateWindow = new EditingTemplateWindow();
```

Вот тут консоль выдает ошибку: `EditingTemplateWindow is not a constructor`.
Вопрос: как можно заставить программу работать? И что возвращает функция `Ext.extend`?

Comment: Что-то не густо ответов :(  
... и просмотров

Comment: С ExtJS не работал, могу только предположить:

    EditingTemplateWindow = function(){
        return Ext.extend(...);
    }

И для проверки: `console.log(Ext.extend(...));` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что `JS`-файлы подгружаются не в правильном порядке. Т.е. `EditingTemplateWindow` тут является как-бы плагином для `EditingTemplateWindowUi` (`EditingTemplateWindow` расширяет `EditingTemplateWindowUi`).
Тогда-то `JavaScript` и начал ругаться на то, что `EditingTemplateWindow` не является конструктором. Это произошло по причине того, что переменная `EditingTemplateWindow` не смогла инициализироваться как надо из-за того, что не было найдено `EditingTemplateWindowUi`, который погружался уже после.

Что касается определения `Ext.extend`, то эта ф-я позволяет осуществить полноценное наследование согласно парадигме ООП. Т.е. эта ф-я возвращает определение нового класса. У этой функции есть два варианта вызова:

```
Ext.extend(Функция_суперкласса, переопределения (или overrides) )
```

и

```
Ext.extend( Функция_подкласс, Функция_суперкласс, переопределения (или overrides))
```

И вот примеры вызова для обоих методов:

```
ex1 = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    //переопределения методов функции (класса) Ext.Window
    //например поля width
    this.width = 666,
    //и не забываем вызвать метод инициализации суперкласса (Ext.Window)
    initComponent: function() {
        EditingTemplateWindow.superclass.initComponent.call(this);//вот оно
    }
});

//вот пример вызова:
var ee = new ex1();
ee.show();
```

Второй

```
function newClass(config) { // конструктор
    config.emptyText = "'5' не допускается";
    newClass.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
Ext.extend(newClass, Ext.form.ComboBox, {
    setValue: function(v) {
        if (v == 5) { // если v равно 5, сообщить пользователю
        alert("'5' не допускается");
    } else { // иначе вызываем метод родителя
        newClass.superclass.setValue.call(this, v);
    }
}
});
```

Ну все.